# Xml to Mysql Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Im trying to get this working, but i do something wrong, im now trying 2 days to get it worked but no luck. Maybe someone can help me with the code

I have a xml file on the internet (see the example) and i want to put that xml in my mysql with php.

This is the example of my XML file

```
<AssignmentItems xmlns="http://server.my.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://server.my.net/static/xsd/datafeed_assignments.xsd" total="29">
<Assignment>
<Id>253049101</Id>
<Status>Enroute</Status>
<Location>EBCI</Location>
<From>EBCI</From>
<Destination>EHGG</Destination>
<Assignment>1 PixCha Passer</Assignment>
<Amount>1</Amount>
<Units>passengers</Units>
<Pay>911.00</Pay>
<PilotFee>0.00</PilotFee>
<Expires>3 days</Expires>
<ExpireDateTime>2017-12-01 06:01:56</ExpireDateTime>
<Type>Trip-Only</Type>
<Express>False</Express>
<Locked>sharee</Locked>
<Comment/>
</Assignment> 
</AssignmentItems>
```

i use this PHP code to send it to my MYSQL

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('**XML URL**');

$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Assignment');
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length;

for  ($i=0; $i < $xmlcount; $i++) {
$Id = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Id')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Status = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Status')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Location = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Location')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Fram = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('From')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Destination = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Destination')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Assignment = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Assignment')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Amount = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Amount')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Units = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Units')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Pay = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Pay')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$PilotFee = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('PilotFee')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Expires = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Expires')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$ExpireDateTime = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('ExpireDateTime')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Type = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Type')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Express = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Express')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$Locked = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('Locked')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into jobs values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $Id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $Status);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $Location);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $Fram);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $Destination);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $Assignment);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $Amount);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $Units);
$stmt->bindParam(9, $Pay);
$stmt->bindParam(10, $PilotFee);
$stmt->bindParam(11, $Expires);
$stmt->bindParam(12, $ExpireDateTime);
$stmt->bindParam(13, $Type);
$stmt->bindParam(14, $Express);
$stmt->bindParam(15, $Locked);
$stmt->execute();
printf($Id.'<br/>');
printf($Status.'<br/>');
printf($Location.'<br/>');
printf($Fram.'<br/>');
printf($Destination.'<br/>');
printf($Assignment.'<br/>');
printf($Amount.'<br/>');
printf($Units.'<br/>');
printf($Pay.'<br/>');
printf($PilotFee.'<br/>');
printf($Expires.'<br/>');
printf($ExpireDateTime.'<br/>');
printf($Type.'<br/>');
printf($Express.'<br/>');
printf($Locked.'<br/>');


}

 ?>
```

Than i get this error on my php page:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function item() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml.php on line 11

I hope someone can help with this error code
Michael

Comment: Remove access key from your question and add sample xml that is enough to reproduce the problem instead.

Comment: You can first get whole xml data in PHP with simplexml_load_file function and then can add all data in loop to MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get whole XML data in PHP with `simplexml_load_file` function and then can add all XML data to database with `for loop` with `MySqli Prepared Statements` like below:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/sample.xml") or die("Error: 
Cannot create object");
$count = count($xml->Assignment);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
$Id = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Id;
$Status = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Status;
$Location = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Location;
$Fram = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Fram;
$Destination = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Destination;
$Assignment = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Assignment;
$Amount = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Amount;
$Units = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Units;
$Pay = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Pay;
$PilotFee = $xml->Assignment[$i]->PilotFee;
$Expires = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Expires;
$ExpireDateTime = $xml->Assignment[$i]->ExpireDateTime;
$Type = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Type;
$Express = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Express;
$Locked = $xml->Assignment[$i]->Locked;
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into jobs values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $Id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $Status);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $Location);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $Fram);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $Destination);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $Assignment);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $Amount);
$stmt->bindParam(8, $Units);
$stmt->bindParam(9, $Pay);
$stmt->bindParam(10, $PilotFee);
$stmt->bindParam(11, $Expires);
$stmt->bindParam(12, $ExpireDateTime);
$stmt->bindParam(13, $Type);
$stmt->bindParam(14, $Express);
$stmt->bindParam(15, $Locked);
$stmt->execute();
printf($Id.'<br/>');
printf($Status.'<br/>');
printf($Location.'<br/>');
printf($Fram.'<br/>');
printf($Destination.'<br/>');
printf($Assignment.'<br/>');
printf($Amount.'<br/>');
printf($Units.'<br/>');
printf($Pay.'<br/>');
printf($PilotFee.'<br/>');
printf($Expires.'<br/>');
printf($ExpireDateTime.'<br/>');
printf($Type.'<br/>');
printf($Express.'<br/>');
printf($Locked.'<br/>');
// Get all data in Variables and Execute MYSQLi Prepared Statements
// ----  //
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer i test it later this day :)

Comment: You are welcome, Michael! Do let me know if you will face any issues :)

Comment: I have now this: https://i.imgur.com/zKvQIPR.png but i think i doing something wrong maybe you can help me if you want? :)

Comment: Sure! I will check and let you know shortly.

Comment: Please replace earlier for loop with for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)

Comment: I have tested offline at my end. Now it will work fine.

Comment: Follow my answer and use simplexml_load_file to load the xml

Comment: I updated complete code in my answer. It must surely work.

Comment: You can also check at https://github.com/amitphpprogrammer/load-xml-in-php

Comment: download files and check offline at your end.

Comment: i can only say one thing, Thank you very much for helping :) i think it is working :D many thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Dont forget to accept my answer and upvote :) Happy Coding.

Comment: i try to vote but i got this: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. (i have make my account today)

Comment: No Issues... I think you can accept the answer only :) just do that.

Comment: I upvote your Question. Now check your points. You will receive 2 more points when you accept my answer but do only if I deserve. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I catch your error. The error is noticed when you try to access item in position 1 and there isn't an item in that position:
When you call this function `$xmlcount = $xmldata->length;` `$xmlcount` has a value of 2 so your `for` loop make an empty cycle with a null data. For avoid this fast without too much control make this:

```
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length - 1;
```

**[Edit]**

Your XML is not formatted correctly. You missed a closed tag of `<AssignmentItems>`

Comment: Thank you for answer, 
i have now this:
$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Assignment');
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length - 1;

but have the same fault code

Comment: No problem :). What you mean with "i have this now"

Comment: i mean that i enter your code line my php file = $xmlcount = $xmldata->length - 1; but that was not fixed for my, or i forgot something?

Comment: sorry my mistake, in forgot to copy past the </AssignmentItems> i have now added in the first post.

Comment: no not working :( i have the same error as in the first post

Comment: This is what i have now: [link]https://i.imgur.com/k5ScDX2.png and this is the fault code [link]https://i.imgur.com/F4ZLBgW.png

Comment: For me work with your XML template. Just try to use $xmldoc->loadXML({paste your XML template}) against $xmldoc->load({url})